# PostgreSQL migration parameter "locale" must be specified

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, entity-framework-5

I've been trying to set up migration in .NET, I have auto-generated migrate files, but there are some problems with it.
When I try to execute this piece code:

```
modelBuilder
    .HasAnnotation("Npgsql:CollationDefinition:insensitive_collation", "en-u-ks-primary,en-u-ks-primary,icu,")
    .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 63)
    .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.4")
    .HasAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn);
```

It says:
`42P17: parameter "locale" must be specified.`
How should I edit  `"en-u-ks-primary,en-u-ks-primary,icu,"`  to fix it?

Edit: I'm using entity-framework 5.0.7

Comment: Is it Entity Framework? Add tag. Specify exact version.

Comment: [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc/collations-and-case-sensitivity.html?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: Edited, I'm using entity framework 5.0.7